# Android arraylist reset index

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an `ArrayList` using the z-axis from the accelerometer with a limit of four elements.

When the fourth element is recorded, it will reset the index of the array to zero and continue the array.

Example: Array = 1 , 2 , 3 , 4

then a new value comes in which is 5

then Array = 5 , 1 , 2 , 3

```
ArrayList<Float> z = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent Event) {
    z.add(Event.values[2]);

    if (z.size() > 3) {
        z.remove(3);
        z.add( 0, Event.values[2] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should use fixed size array instead and just write the logic in the paper first if figuring it out in the code is giving you a headache. This smells like homework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want 4 values just use an array.

Also keep the index that's added to and use modulo to reset it

```
float[] events = new float[4];
int eventIndex;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent Event) {
   events[ (++eventIndex) % events.length ] = Event.values[2];
}
```

---

Or if you want to create a "stack" (or actually, a queue) that pushes out the end, then you probably should limit where you add the data based on the size, and not add the element twice when you do reach that size.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent Event) {
    float value = Event.values[2];
    if (z.size() <= 3) {
        z.add(value);
    } else {
        z.add(0, value);
        z.remove(z.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it did not work, i need it so when the event happens then the data is stored in index zero and the rest of the data is shifted right.

Comment: thanks for your help, I voted for your answer although i am not sure if it registered because i recently joined.

Comment: You can't upvote with less than 10 rep. If the answer solved your problem, you can use the checkmark, otherwise, you can comment to say that is still isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a method to achieve the input as per your requirement.

```
public static void addToList(String s){
     if(list.size()>=5){
         list.add(0,s);
         for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 4; i--) {
            list.remove(i);
         }  }
    else if(list.size()<=4){
       list.add(s);
     }
  }
```

[image]